# Printing background colours in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, printing

I'm trying to print a php generated document in Chrome. On the browser it looks fine, but my printer will not print any coloured backgrounds. I know that IE has an option to print background but Chrome does not.

As the end user will print this off, I do not want to find alternatives like a screen grab or save file etc. I want to find a real solution to this.

[Here is the page i want to print, for information](http://www.abbeysoft.co.uk/adi/241/quote.php)

Can anyone offer a suggestion please?

Answer (score 3):

There's a long long two years old thread at Chrome support, full of users complaining exactly how ludicrous is the lack of so basic function, as background printing, in Chrome.

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=17a4ac343580c8d3&hl=en

TWO Years!

My advice is to use Firefox or Opera until we get heard at Google.

Comment: basic sure, popular, no.

Comment: there's a solution now! see down there!

Answer (score 3):

There is now a chrome extension that injects `-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact`. I tested it with Chrome 23 and works fine.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/print-background-colors/gjecpgdgnlanljjdacjdeadjkocnnamk

Answer (score 2):

CSS to allow chrome to print backgrounds:

See here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355117/print-css-backgrounds-in-safari-chrome/9339257#9339257

Answer (score 0):

Considering that it seems to me that the OP was "CREATING" the page, this belongs to stackoverflow rather then SuperUser.

In any case, the good solution is... NOT to use background-color and background-image!
...also because Chrome is still not supporting printing them (Jan 2012!), and even with other browsers the user have to go through printing options...

If you are creating the page it's reasonable. See for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2966004/422670

I use something like:

```
<div class='container'>
    <img src='background-image or color' class='background'/>
    normal stuff as it should be
</div>
```

then in css:

```
img.background {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

of course you can then adapt the css and the classes to your use

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's finally coming:

for the moment in the form of a specific -webkit style:

see http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2294

```
-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
```

I could not find an option in chrome but if you are editing the page you can add it; otherwise simply fire the developers tool and add this style to the body.

Works!!!!!!

A very different answer from myself ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of printing it directly from the browser, try taking a screen shot and printing it from an image editor.

Comment: Doesn't work if it's more than one screen long. Also, most designers will set different styles for screen and print using the `media` attribute of the style tag: fonts that work better in each media, maybe removing images or ads from the printed version, etc. Printing from a screenshot defeats this effort.

Answer (score -1):

Use Internet Explorer as this option is not in Chrome. Go to `file - page setup - print background colors and images` and **check** it.

Or, in IE, go to `tools - internet options - advanced - printing - print background colors and images`

Comment: -1 This question is specifically about Google Chrome. If the user asked "How can I do X in Ubuntu?", responding with "You can do X in Windows by..." would not be a good answer.