# Chrome print background images

Tags: google-chrome, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Printing background colours in Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/117162/printing-background-colours-in-chrome)

I'm trying to print a PHP generated document in Chrome. On the browser it looks fine. But my printer will not print any coloured backgrounds. I know that Internet Explorer has an option to print background but Chrome does not. As the end user will print this off I do not want to find alternatives like a screen grab or save file, etc. I want to find a real solution to this.

How can I fix it?

Comment: This question is the exact duplicate of your previous one: http://superuser.com/questions/117162/printing-background-colours-in-chrome. Do not duplicate questions. There are other things to do if you don't get a correct answer to your question, as explained in the FAQ (http://superuser.com/faq).

Comment: It's not an *exact* duplicate: he added the vital detail that this is something he needs for end users, not himself. But I agree, it would be better to add that information to the original question, rather than re-asking the question.

Comment: @Martha If he has new information, he should simply edit his original question.

Comment: Which is what I said...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ckibcdccnfeookdmbahgiakhnjcddpki) Chrome extension?

Otherwise, you just answered your question yourself

> ... IE has an option to print background but chrome does not.

Comment: Fact that there is no option visible doesn't necessarily mean there is not a way to do it.