# How can I print background colors and images in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Printing background colours in Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/117162/printing-background-colours-in-chrome)

This was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392366/print-background-colours-in-chrome) over a year ago... I'm on version 10.0.648.151 of Chrome...

How can I print what I see on the screen?

Comment: Could you just copy and paste into notepad, or a rich text editor and print from there?

Comment: typically that changes the layout / fonts / and other "looks" but in the end what you see in the other "editor" you paste to is what you get when printed... it just no longer looks like it does in the browser.